# Imprimir datos de un request GET con axios

Tags: javascript, axios

no se mucho de js, por ahora necesito imprimir los datos que me devuelve la API que estoy consultando con axios, no puedo acceder al objeto que quiero mostrar ya que es un array, según lo que me muestra el console.log, necesito llegar hasta comments, que es lo que quiero imprimir. De antemano muchas gracias!

```
<script>
axios.get('https://readservices-b2c.powerreviews.com/m/587047/l/en_US/product/2/reviews?apikey=5d683735-a2e1-4281-bd56-477f5da8365e')
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response.data);
  review.innerHTML = response.data["results"];
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
</script>
```

Salida del console.log: (tiene mas datos, pero preferi dejarlo hasta ahí, que básicamente es lo que necesito. Ojo esto comments se repiten varias veces, que es parte de la data que estoy consultando).

```
{configuration: {…}, name: "review", paging: {…}, results: Array(1)}
configuration: {localizations: {…}, properties: {…}, features: {…}}
name: "review"
paging: {total_results: 9, pages_total: 1, page_size: 10, current_page_number: 1}
results: Array(1)
0:
page_id: "2"
reviews: Array(9)
0:
badges: {is_staff_reviewer: false, is_verified_buyer: false, is_verified_reviewer: true}
details:
bottom_line: "Yes"
comments: "Thank you for helping me in my wellness journey."
```

[image: Salida console.log(response.data)]

Esto fue lo que termine haciendo, pero ahora me queda la duda de como hacer que [0] al lado de results, sea dinámico (por darle un nombre), ya que como en la imagen anterior, es un array y necesito imprimir todos.

[image: Resultado finalmente pude imprimir los datos!]

Comment: Antes de contestar, tienes conocimiento sobre la diferencia entre un [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) y un [Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos)? No te serviría mucho si contestará sin más, si no conoces los conceptos =/

Comment: CUal de todos los comments que vienen en el arreglo quieres mostrar, todos, el primero , el ultimo?

Comment: Gracias @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas el último! Sólo que para llegar a él necesito recorrer los otros, y como en el ejemplo, si intento imprimir result por ser un objeto no lo muestra. (Es decir un objeto, con multiples tipos de datos). Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Que pasa si pones: `review.innerHTML = response.data["results"].pop().comments;`

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas me lo muestra como indefinido. Colo que una imagen con la salida del console.log el tema esta en que ese atributo esta dentro del array 0 1 2 3 4 5, etc.

Comment: Ya logre mostrarlo, sabía que era la forma en como esta armando el array, pero ahora me gustaria saber, como hacer para reperit dentro del mismo array los demas objetos, ya que no es algo que será fijo, el array (por darle un nombre), seguirá creciendo.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente lo termine resolviendo de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
axios.get('https://readservices-b2c.powerreviews.com/m/587047/l/en_US/product/2/reviews?apikey=5d683735-a2e1-4281-bd56-477f5da8365e')
.then(function(response){
  var results = response.data["results"]["0"]["reviews"];
  for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    var item = results[i];
    console.log(item.details.headline);

    review.innerHTML += item.details.headline +
   '<br/>Would you recommend vitalmins to a friend?:  ' + item.details["bottom_line"] + 
   '<br/>' + item.details["comments"] + 
   '<br/> by:  ' + item.details["nickname"] + '<br/>';
  }
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
</script>
```